# Flutter - Riverpod 2.0 - .select() function is not preventing unnecessary rebuilds at all, .select() is not working

Tags: flutter, riverpod

i'm using state notifier and state notifier provider with select to only apply rebuild to specific field in the object. but the whole widget rebuild whether i selected or not.

i have the following example code to simplify my problem:

```
final counterProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CounterState, Counter>((ref) => CounterState());

class Counter {
  int count1;
  int count2;

  Counter(this.count1, this.count2);
}

class CounterState extends StateNotifier<Counter> {
  CounterState() : super(Counter(0, 0));

  void inc1() => state = Counter(state.count1 + 1, state.count2);

  void inc2() => state = Counter(state.count1, state.count2 + 1);
}
```

and the following consumer widget:

```
class TestWidget extends ConsumerWidget {

  const TestWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) => Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
      Text(ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) {
        print("rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: ${value.count1}");
        return value.count1.toString();
      }))),
      Text(ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) {
        print("rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: ${value.count2}");
        return value.count2.toString();
      }))),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).inc1(),
          child: const Text("Inc 1")),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).inc2(),
          child: const Text("Inc 2"))
        ],
      ));
}
```

i'm excpecting when pressing the `inc1()` button to not rebuild the second text. only the first.

but the output in the console when i press inc1 for 3 times is the following:

```
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 0
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
D/EGL_emulation(19394): app_time_stats: avg=417.64ms min=8.70ms max=4924.00ms count=13
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 1
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 1
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
D/EGL_emulation(19394): app_time_stats: avg=78.42ms min=2.63ms max=1171.43ms count=18
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 2
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 2
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
D/EGL_emulation(19394): app_time_stats: avg=34.74ms min=2.47ms max=721.10ms count=25
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 3
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 3
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
```

and i'm expecting in the console:

```
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 0
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: 0
D/EGL_emulation(19394): app_time_stats: avg=417.64ms min=8.70ms max=4924.00ms count=13
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 1
D/EGL_emulation(19394): app_time_stats: avg=78.42ms min=2.63ms max=1171.43ms count=18
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 2
D/EGL_emulation(19394): app_time_stats: avg=34.74ms min=2.47ms max=721.10ms count=25
I/flutter (19394): rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: 3
```

so what am i not understanding correctly about `select()` function?
and why the first text is rebuilt twice although the change occur once?

Comment: you want to separate the state,like here state contains with two count value`Counter`, and to update the state, you need to assign new instance.

Comment: assign a new instance where exactly? if you mean at the `inc1()` function, i already assigned a new instance. if else where  then can you tell me where do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean once you ` state = Counter..` it create new instance and both value get changed being new obj

Comment: yes this is correct. i'm trying to follow the principles of immutable state management. do you mean i can't perform what i want to do with immutable state management?

Answer (score 5):

The `select` function is unrelated to the problem described.

`select` is for skipping some updates which you don't care about. In your care about the update, but want to rebuild fewer widgets.

To do that the solution is to either:

- Extract your individual texts as a separate `ConnsumerWidget`
- wrap your texts into a `Consumer`

Like:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) {
      return Text(ref.watch(fooProvider));
    }),
    Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) {
      return Text(ref.watch(barProvider));
    }),
  ],
)
```

This way, an update on `fooProvider` will not rebuild the text which listens to `barProvider`

Comment: i figured this solution before.. but how is the problem is unrelated to select?
according to the document provided the select function does the following: _"a widget/provider may only care about changes to some properties instead of the whole object."_ . which state that the benefits of using select is to watch a part of an object, please correct me if i'm wrong with a plain explanation of the usage of select.

Comment: @MohaAmiry You're not listening to part of an object. You're listening to the entire object, but listening to two different providers in two different parts of your widget tree.

Comment: I understood the consumer method, but i can't understand how my example is not suited for `select()`.. my example is almost identical to the `user` example in the documents where you watched a single field (`user.name`), expect that my example is a state notifier, not a plain class, can i see an example of `select()` that truly distictify it's true usage from my usage in my example?

Comment: No the example is fundamentally different. Your case would be similar if your widget wanted to render only the `string.length` or the first character. Then select could be used to not have the UI rebuild unless the length/first character changed.

Comment: TD;DR you're not trying to reduce how often your UI updates. You're trying to reduce the number of widgets impacted by the update.

Comment: Thank you very much, i understand what you mean now :)

Comment: just to notify remi, although you stated this in the document of .select(), the usage spread across the internet is similar to my usage, and even your document in riverpod website doesn't focus on this conditions like (`string.length`). i would strongly recommend adding an explicit example over this condition to. :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```dart
class TestWidget extends ConsumerWidget {

  const TestWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) => Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
     Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) { // added this
      Text(ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) {
        print("rebuilt counter 1 Text with val: ${value.count1}");
        return value.count1.toString();
      }))),
     }),
     Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) { // added this
      Text(ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) {
        print("rebuilt Counter 2 Text with val: ${value.count2}");
        return value.count2.toString();
      }))),
     }),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).inc1(),
          child: const Text("Inc 1")),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).inc2(),
          child: const Text("Inc 2"))
        ],
      ));
}
```

This is because you are using `ref`, which is in the scope of `TestWidget`. You must use a separate widget or use the `Consumer` wrapper. This was described by @Rémi Rousselet

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ruble, @Rémi Rousselet
i did this solution before and it worked as i said.. but a problem occurs when i have a situation like this:

```
class Counter {
  int count1;
  int count2;
  Color count1Color;
  Counter(this.count1, this.count2,this.count1Color);
}
```

and i can change the color the same way i did with `inc1()` and `inc2()`, through a procedure..

```
Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) =>
                    Text(ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) =>
                        value.count1.toString()))
                      , style: TextStyle(color: ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) => value
                          .count1Color))),)), 
                // a color for count1 editable through a button for example.
                // if i change the state of the color the the text
                // will be rebuild too! so back to the same problem!
                
                Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) =>
                    Text(ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) =>
                        value.count2.toString())))),
```

so where is the problem? there is still some situations for example where i want to watch a decoration of an object through a composite state notifier like this example above. the solution of nested consumer widgets doesn't always work, because in the situation above the `style` property doesn't accept a value of type consumer because it is not a widget.

what can i do in situations like this?

i need change the text of the counter and it's color using state notifier provider, without any redundant rebuilts.